# setting current link as active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using [metis menu](https://github.com/onokumus/metisMenu) like

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Choose action<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level in">
           <li>
               <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Home</a>
           </li>
           <li>
               <a href="@Url.Action("Account", "Login")"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Login</a>
               </li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

> When clicking on home action link I'm getting this link with css class
>   active as it should. But problem is that when I click on other link
>   login action this link is also decorated with action link together
>   with home link.

How can I set css class active to only this currently "selected" link?

Comment: I was thinking to use viewbag and to inject from server side controller active link but that seems like overkill for this situation.

Comment: Use may use approach explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169346/how-to-change-nav-links-color-according-to-page-when-using-php/35169531#35169531

Comment: Yeah. This approach is good @GauravRai. *Lucknowi Nawaab*

Answer (score 0):

You can use following `js` to set current link active.

```
$('.nav a').each(function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf(this.href) > -1) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    }
});
```